Micropython time.time_ns() having a 1-second resolution?
I'm currently learning to work with Micropython on an RPI2040-based board.
During this process, I  noticed an unexpected behavior from the time module.
I wrote a simple loop printing the time in ns every half second
import time
while True:
    print(time.time_ns())
    time.sleep(0.5)

which gave me the following output
1713442861000000000
1713442861000000000
1713442862000000000
1713442862000000000
1713442863000000000
1713442863000000000

It seems that time.time_ns() actually does the same thing as time.time() (which only gives full seconds) but with 9 zeros at the end. I have also found this post which points to the same issue on an Rpi Pico (also built on the RP2040) and meuh's answers seems to indicate that time.ticks_us() is the answer fo smaller time resolution.
I have two questions :

Is this 1-second resolution in time.time_ns() an issue of the RP2040, or of Micropython ?

Why would the developers create a time_ns() method if it is no better than time.time() ? It is very misleading and not useful to anyone.



Just a guess for number 2. It might be part of a standard, so it has to be implemented, but the hardware doesn't support that level of precision, so it gives you a number that still fits the right units, but doesn't have much accuracy. In short, its for compatibility

The chip name is RP2040, not RPI2040.

What version of MicroPython are you using?  I can't reproduce this with v1.22.1-g9b8c64c9c.  The numbers printed by your code on my RP2040 board are like 1609459282610064000 so they have microsecond resolution.  Your output looks suspiciously like a Unix timestamp (for 2024-04-18 12:21:01 UTC), not an arbitrary counter.  Did you show us all the code or are you doing something else in your system to set up a real-time clock?  How could your Raspberry Pi Pico possibly know the real time?

I don't think there's any reason to be swearing at us -- or the micropython authors -- in your question.

@David Grayson
I'm using Micropython v1.20.0-62-g4e4bdbd19
I am connecting my board to my PC and running the code I posted on the board through the Thonny IDE of my PC, so idk if this affects the behavior of the board ?
My board is actually the Pololu 3pi+ 2040 robot. Don't know if that helps (sorry I'm very much a newbie).

I think you are correct.Currently micropython has 1-second resolution in time.time_ns().Just check this commit 10702

Yasantha found the commit  where this issue was fixed.  That commit has been incorporated into Micropython v1.21.0 and later, so you should be able to fix it by updating your MicroPython version.  Of course you could also just use time.ticks_us() to get microsecond resolution.
